# Is it possible to get the Cargo environment variable information for one crate using another crate?

Tags: rust

I have a crate that provides this functionality:

```
pub fn version_info() -> u16 {
    // simplified for minimal example
    env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR").parse().unwrap()
}
```

If I use the library as so, I'll get the major version of the library crate:

```
use mylib;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", mylib::version_info());
}
```

Is it possible to get the major version of the "current" crate but using another crate to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR` and other `CARGO_*` variables are set by Cargo during the compilation of the crate ([Cargo reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-crates)), so, for example, you can't read it at runtime with [`std::env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html).

One way would be to write a macro in `mylib`:

```rust
macro_rules! version_info {
    () => {
        env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR").parse::<u32>().unwrap()
    }
}
```

and use it in your crate (note the `!`):

```rust
use mylib;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", mylib::version_info!());
}
```

Macros get expanded during compilation and Cargo variables are available.